Method of inserting random numbers in the numerical calculation of mean-squared displacement for brownian particle
I am trying to plot Mean-Squared-Displacement for a passive Brownian particle. For that I'm using the discretized over-damped version of the Langevin equation as: $$x(i+1)=x(i)+\sqrt{\frac{2.k_BT.\Delta t}{\gamma}}.w_i\tag{1}$$
For MSD calculation I'm using the equation: $$\langle \Delta x^2(\Delta t) \rangle=\frac{1}{N.N_{t_0}}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{t_0}\left( x(t_0+\Delta t)-x(t_0) \right)^2.$$
The $w_i$'s are just Gaussian white noise.
But my question is regarding the implementation of this stuff in a fortran code.
If I use random_seed() for each particle, then (say) for a total time $T=10$ with time-step $\Delta t=0.001$, we get 10,000 identical random numbers for a particle. That is, say for particle #1, in equation (1), we get $w_1=0.965458$. And this random number will be same throughout. That is $w_1=w_2=...=w_{9999}=w_{10000}=0.965458.$
If I change the seed for the next particle, the resulting scenario will be something like this, $w_1=w_2=...=w_{9999}=w_{10000}=0.483256.$ And so on for all the other particles.
But I want to know what should be the process regarding random number insertion?
Do we have to use different random_seed() for different particles?
Say I put "seed=500000" for 1st particle, "seed=600000" for 2nd particle. Then we shall get $w^1_1=w^1_2=...=w^1_{9999}=w^1_{10000};$$ w^2_1=w^2_2=...=w^2_{9999}=w^2_{10000}$. But how can the noise value be the same in a Brownian motion!
If we dismiss the random_seed() thing altogether, all $w_i$ values for all particles are different, totally random. But this is difficult for reproducibility purpose! So there should be some form of seed in our code. But i'm unable to get the actual process.
What is the process and the science behind it?

I won't debug your code, but I'd set the random seed once

Have you read the documentation on random_seed?

Since I got rid of a significant doubt I thought of answering myself.

We have to write the script for a single particle.
We need to set seed once, at the beginning. And it should take care of consecutive random numbers for step-increments.
In this way, we have to run the same code but for 500 (say) different seeds. This is 'ensemble averaging'.
This is one process. So we need not run the code for more than one particle.

